# Issue with minifying files when bundling with RollupJS rollup-plugin-multientry using rollup-plugin-uglify

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs, rollup

I'm trying to bundle quite a few JavaScript files into a single minified file using rollup-plugin-multi-entry and rollup-plugin-uglify. I'm new to minifying files so the only thing that throws a red flag is that my IDE's theme isn't changing the color of my code when I bundle multiple files and then minify it compared to when I bundle a single file and minify that one.

Single file works:

```
export default {
   input: 'src/scripts/components/googleAnalytics.js',
   output: {
       file: 'google.min.js',
       format: 'cjs'
     },
     plugins: [ babel(), uglify() ]
}
```

Multiple files don't work:

```
export default {
        input: 'src/scripts/components/bootstrap/*.js',
        output: {
            file: 'bootstrapped.min.js',
            format: 'cjs'
        },
        plugins: [multiEntry(), babel(), uglify({}) ]
    }
```

I'm using a rollup config file and when I run my script in Node it doesn't throw any errors and bundles the new file but doesn't seem to minify it properly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are passing uglify an empty configuration object on the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> a red flag is that my IDE's theme isn't changing the color of my code when I bundle multiple files

This is because it can consume too much memory to keep syntax highlighting for large files; [this Github comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34240#issuecomment-329118862) from a VS 
 Code team member may prove insightful.

This is the case for many IDEs, not just VS Code.